# Create different URLs for different languages with htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am trying to create different URLs for different languages, for example http://localhost/shift/en **without "en" being an actual folder** (shift is an actual sub folder). I want the 'en' to be a variable I can use in my PHP code. Here is how my htaccess looks like:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /shift/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ public/index.php [QSA,L]

RewriteRule ^(en|de|fr)/(.*)$  $2?lang=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$  $1?lang=en [L,QSA]
```

Here's my PHP code:

```
var_dump($_GET['lang']);
```

When I go to http://localhost/shift/en it gives me a 404 and a PHP error: "undefined index: lang".

Answer (score 1):

You need to edit your `.htaccess` like this-

`RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ index.php?lang=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ index.php?lang=$1`

and the **index.php**:

`echo $_GET['lang'];`

If the url is- `http://example.com/en`, then the output will be- `en`

You can do the other things then, with the language.

If you want to give different versions of the page, I recommend you using a page  for each language and include them if a language is asked for in the url.

For example- If someone types `http://example.com/en`, in the **index.php** you need to do this-

```
 if($_GET['lang']=="en") {
     $_SESSION['language']="en"; //Adding a session makes your life easier
     include("en.php");
 //everything else
    }
```

I have updated the rewrite rule. Check it out.

Comment: When I add the rule you wrote, I get an "Internal Server Error".